# Quasilinear 1st order partial differential equation [n-component chemical potential]

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

Disclaimer: This is related to physics, but the problem is essentially a mathematical one (check the *mathematically reduced* version below, which condenses relevant information).

In [Masao Doi's *Soft Matter Physics*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ccUaBj73PZsC&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=(d)%20Consider%20the%20situation%20that%20the%20volume%20fraction%20masao%20doi&source=bl&ots=GrtRV3g5TF&sig=ACfU3U1t5IPjMwSqEsPTh5Ng5oFZArhpUA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUmcvhl53hAhUQ1uAKHSmZC4cQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=(d)%20Consider%20the%20situation%20that%20the%20volume%20fraction%20masao%20doi&f=false) exercise 2.4 d), 
given $\Pi(\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n)$,  $f(\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n)$, $\mu_i(\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n)$, and $P,v_i,k_B,T=cte$, we know 
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} \phi_{i} &= 1 \tag 0 \\
\Pi &= -f+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \phi_{i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi_{i}}+f(0)\tag 1\\
\mu_{i} &= v_{i}\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi_{i}}+P-\Pi+f(0)\right] \text {, for } i=1, \ldots n \tag 2
\end{align}

In this particular case,

\begin{align}\Pi=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\phi_{i}}{v_{i}} k_{B} T+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} A_{i j} \phi_{i} \phi_{j} \tag 3
\end{align}

and we need to show

\begin{align}\mu_{i}=\mu_{i}^{0}(T)+P v_{i}+k_{B} T \ln \phi_{i}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(2 v_{i} A_{i j}-\frac{v_i}{v_j}k_{B} T\right) \phi_{j} \tag 4
\end{align}

I am trying to take the same approach as in page 13 - "merge" the derivatives with $f$ in the rhs of (1), then substitute (3) in (1), and solve for $f$ (by integration) - but I am having trouble with "merging", and then integrating.

Any suggestions?
$$\\ \\$$

**Reduced version**:

Given 
$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, with
\begin{align}
-f+\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}+f(0)=a\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{x_{i}}{v_{i}}+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} A_{i j} x_{i} x_{j} \tag a
\end{align}

show that, for $i=1,...,n$,

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}-\big( a\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{x_{k}}{v_{k}}+\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} A_{k j} x_{k} x_{j} \big) = 
\frac{a}{v_i} \ln x_{i}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(2 A_{i j}-\frac{a}{v_j}\right) x_{j} \tag b
\end{align}

A hint on how to get $f$ or $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}$ would already be a tremendous help.